# Bind mongodb json to kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am very new to kendo UI and getting similar challenges as below(except I dont mind having a fixed data structure for grid):

[How to pass MongoDb Json value to KendoUI grid using webservice method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739729/how-to-pass-mongodb-json-value-to-kendoui-grid-using-webservice-method)

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({

        dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://localhost:8080/urlPath",
                dataType: "json",
               }
            },
    schema: {
            data: "score"
        }
    columns:[{
        field: "physics"
    },
    {
        field: "chemistry",
    }],
   });
```

Json looks like:

```
[{"score"[{"physics:99", "chemistry" :95}]},{"score"[{"physics:99", "chemistry" :95}]}]
```

I am struggling from last few days and have tried approaches like:

[Convert dbcursor object into json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986378/convert-dbcursor-object-into-json)

http://www.codeconfuse.com/2014/03/mongodb-convert-data-getting-from.html

Here's the related code from above URL:

```
    while(cursor.hasNext()) { 
        BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        BasicDBList name = (BasicDBList) obj.get("Name");
        jsonobj.put("Incident Date", obj.getString("Incident Date"));
        jsonarray.put(jsonobj);
  }
  return jsonarray;
JSON json =new JSON();
String serialize = json.serialize(cursor);
```

But the kendo Grid seems to be rejecting it. Please assist.

Comment: I am able to fix the issue. The issue was with the format of json sent by mongoDB. I will reply with the detailed update soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved by formatting the json returned in an appropriate format as below:

From:

```
[{"score"[{"physics:99", "chemistry" :95}]},{"score"[{"physics:99", "chemistry" :95}]**}]**
```

To:

```
[{"physics:99", "chemistry" :95}]},{"score"[{"physics:99", "chemistry" :95}]
```

So, basically I extracted the score object, put into my own hashmap and then returned the json object. See below for sample code:

*

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("score",true).append("_id",false);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query,fields)

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject obj = cursor.next();
    BasicDBList scoreList = (BasicDBList) obj.get("score");

for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.size(); i++) {
        BasicDBObject scoreObj = (BasicDBObject) scoreList.get(i);
        String physics = scoreObj.getString("physics");
        String chemistry = scoreObj.getString("chemistry");
        //ofcourse we need another innerloop here to iterate through
        //all the rows of the returned list.   
        innerMap.add("physics",physics);
        innerMap.add("chemistry",chemistry);
    }       
return new Gson().gson(map.values);
}
```

*